# SQL column and datetime field not updating when using case

Tags: database, t-sql, data-warehouse

I have a dimension table updating from a stage table the 1st condition is that dim.dim_patient.Determination_Code=patient.Determination_Code after which other fields should update if there is a difference spotted in any of the fields below. It is not picking up the changes and when it does update the field it doesn't update the corresponding dss_update_time field.

```
            drop table  #dim_patient
            CREATE TABLE #dim_patient(
                [id] [varchar](20) NULL,
                [episode] [int] NULL,
                [Status_date] [date] NULL,
                [Determination_Code] [varchar](40) NULL,
                [Determination] [varchar](40) NULL,
                [Status_Code] [varchar](40) NULL,
                [Status_Value] [varchar](40) NULL,
                [Days] [int] NULL,
                [RTP_Date] [varchar](500) NULL,
                [PET_Date] [date] NULL,
                [dss_create_time] [datetime] NULL,
                [dss_update_time] [datetime] NULL
                )

            ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            --primary keys are patid and episode number 
            --when Determination_Code is the same status_date should remain the same 
            --every other record should update 
            -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            INSERT INTO #dim_patient VALUES
            ('1435','4','2019-08-01','2','Not Ready',NULL,  NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL ,'2022-09-08 13:49:20.660','2022-09-08 13:49:20.660')
            ,('1435','5','2021-10-12','1','Ready ', 'Yes','Yes','50','2022-11-02',NULL,'2022-09-08 13:49:20.660','2022-11-08 17:04:39.233')

            select * from #dim_patient


             UPDATE [dim].[dim_patient] WITH ( TABLOCK )

             SET 
              ----Status_date        = patient.Status_date    
            , Determination_Code =  patient.Determination_Code
            , Determination      =  patient.Determination
            , Status_Code   =  patient.Status_Code
            , Status_Value  =  patient.Status_Value
            , Days          =  patient.Days
            , RTP_Date      = patient.RTP_Date
            , PET_Date      =  patient.PET_Date
                

            ,dss_update_time =
                    ---= getdate() 
            CASE WHEN dim_patient.Status_Code <> patient.Status_Code
            THEN  getdate()
            WHEN dim_patient.Days <> patient.Days
            THEN  getdate() 
            WHEN dim_patient.RTP_Date <> patient.RTP_Date
            THEN  getdate() 
            WHEN dim_patient.PET_Date <>  patient.PET_Date
            THEN getdate()  
            ELSE dim.dim_patient.dss_update_time
            END


            FROM  [stage].[patient] patient
            JOIN dim.dim_patient
            ON   dim.dim_patient.id=patient.id
            AND  dim.dim_patient.episode=patient.episode
            where  dim.dim_patient.Determination_Code=patient.Determination_Code 
            AND (
                 ( dim.dim_patient.Status_Code <>patient.Status_Code) 
               OR ( dim.dim_patient.Days <> patient.Days)
                 OR ( dim.dim_patient.RTP_Date <> patient.RTP_Date)
                   OR  (dim.dim_patient.PET_Date <> patient.PET_Date)
                    )
```

Comment: Are any of the fields you're doing <> checks on either starting as NULL, or being made NULL? Because in `CASE WHEN dim_patient.SRTF_Status_Code <> patient.SRTF_Status_Code` if either one of them (or both) is NULL, then the check isn't successful (e.g., will not set dss_update_time to `getdate()`)

Comment: @seanb you are right they are accepting nulls. I have modified the code to have an idea of the date.